# Illustrator CS5 clipboard error

Tags: pdf, clipboard, adobe-illustrator

I get an error while trying to copy any data from Illustrator and paste it to Photoshop via clipboard. Even if you just copy something in Illustrator and switch to another application, illustrator shows the error. I can paste the object back into the same document without any problems, but when moving to Photoshop or other app the computer freezes up for a second, sounds so nasty "ding" and then the error window pops up:

`An operation is not completed due to unknown error [PDF!]`

Adobe CS5. Deleting and reinstalling did not help as well as a Temp folder cleaning. I have in my company exactly the same version and copying through clipboard works! Checked on viruses, but NOD keeps silent, so i suppose everything fine with it. Maybe someone had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to clean Temp folder? There are must be two such folders.
In any case I would go to the Preferences-File handlink and disable PDF. As for viruses it is better run mbam. I don't trust NOD and other..

Find an answer in other discussions. Unfortunately, here are not many people willing to help. It might help: https://forums.adobe.com/message/6492212  or maybe another. This is the official Adobe forum, so you can find a solution there, i suppose.

Almost forgot to say. It can be a local illustrator incompatibility with the clipboard, or the clipboard is intercepted by one of the programs. Maybe the existence of a specific font in the layout is affected. Try to copy simple primitive objects.